# Check Selected value already in table's row Id

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I have a dropdownlist and selected items added to the table.In here i want to restrict the duplicate record addition.In here i can do this using Selected value(This value is also a table row id )

```
<select id="drpnews">
<option value="0" text="select">-- Select--</option>
<option value="1">News 1</option>
<option value="2">News 2</option>
<option value="3">News 3</option>
<option value="4">News 4</option>
</select>


 for (var i = 0; i < nArray.length; i++) {
            nTable += "<tr id=" + $("#drpnews :selected").val() + ">";

            nTable += "<td>";
            nTable += nArray[i]['NewsName']
            nTable += "</td>";

            nTable += "<td>";
            nTable += nArray[i]['Globe']
            nTable += "</td>";
           }
           nTable += "</tbody></table>";
```

Here i have tried like this.but failed.(It failed always - comes out of the if statement)

```
if ($("#nTable tr:contains('" + $("#drpnews :selected").val() + "')").length) {

            alert("News Already Exists!");

        }
```

Comment: have you tested by changing `"#drpnews :selected"` to `"#drpnews:selected"`

Comment: yes.result is same

Comment: can you add a mock html template

Comment: Your `html`doesn't seem valid as multiple items have same id which is not allowed.

Comment: you don't need to use :selected if you want to get the value from select $('#drpnews').val()

Answer (score 0):

Just check if an element with an Id equals to the selected value exists.

```
var id = $("#drpnews option:selected").val();
if($('tr#'+ id).length)
     alert("News already exists!");
```